# Passing properties object (with onclick function using this.id) to HTML element constructor function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an HTML button with JS and I'm defining the onclick function using a element constructing function I wrote/copied from Marijn Haverbeke's [Eloquent Javascript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/)

I am creating a button that needs to pass `this.id` to the onclick function. The onclick function runs, but `this.id` is coming through in `packItem()` as undefined.

This method of creating buttons has been working great for me but I can't get the `this.id` to come through into `packItem()`.

Run code snippet to obtain the `undefined` id:

```js
let element = elt(
  "button", {
    id: "test_id",
    onclick: () => packItem(this.id),
  },
  "packed"
)

document.body.appendChild(element);

function packItem(id) {
  console.log("packing item:", id);
}


function elt(type, props, ...children) {
  let element = document.createElement(type);
  if (props) Object.assign(element, props);
  for (let child of children) {
    // console.log(typeof child);
    if (typeof child != "string") element.appendChild(child);
    else element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(child));
  }
  return element;
}
```

I assumed the problem lies in how `this.id` is getting transferred through the prop object being added to the element in `elt()` but can't figure out why exactly and then I tried adding the onclick after my elt function, which ruled out my incorrect assumption above. What am I doing wrong!?

```
 let thisbutton = elt(
    "button",
    {
      id: `${customer_id}/${value.id}`,
      // onclick: () => packItem(this.id),
    },
    "packed"
  );
  thisbutton.onclick = () => packItem(this.id);
```

doesn't work either....

I realize that I am not passing anything to packItem() when I write as `() => packItem(this.id)` but `onclick: (this.id) => packItem(this.id)` returns: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target`
and I've tried simply defining onclick this way: `onclick: packItem(this.id)` but then packItem() doesn't even run.

Comment: You should not use an arrow function, but a `function`.

Comment: You're right, but then it does not run on the click...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change arrow function to the normal `function`.

```
let element = elt(
  "button", {
    id: "test_id",
    onclick: function(){packItem(this.id)},
  },
  "packed"
)

document.body.appendChild(element);

function packItem(id) {
  console.log("packing item:", id);
}


function elt(type, props, ...children) {
  let element = document.createElement(type);
  if (props) Object.assign(element, props);
  for (let child of children) {
    // console.log(typeof child);
    if (typeof child != "string") element.appendChild(child);
    else element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(child));
  }
  return element;
}
```

Comment: This works! Could you please explain why the arrow function doesn't? I thought the arrow function () => {} was the way to be able to see props (this.id) above the inner block and the function(){} definition wouldn't be able to see this.id...